# Error starting ApplicationContext . o.s. boot application run failed

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am working on a project and trying to configure my application with my database at MongoDB. I am not able to run my file due to the following errors. I am attaching my application file below:

```
package engineer.aviralmishra.Project_20051515;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Project20051515Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Project20051515Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

It is throwing the following 2 exceptions :

1. Application run failed.
2. DataBase name cannot contain dots, slash , dollar sign.

I am attaching the thrown exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-11T01:00:40.571+05:30 ERROR 30016 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at engineer.aviralmishra.Project_20051515.Project20051515Application.main(Project20051515Application.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:122) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport.<init>(MongoDatabaseFactorySupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java:75) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java:64) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.mongoDatabaseFactory(MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 25 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```